# How to handle wrong width calculation when sizing text-overflow div?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, overflow

I am creating a [splitter-resizer in Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve1xxf) to adjust the width of 2 panels. There are 2 horizontal sections and the columns widths on each side needs to be the same. However, I noticed that the width calculation is wrong at the boundary that touches the text overflow element. This causes the top and bottom panels to be off by roughly the size of a single text character.

What can I do to ensure the div width respects the ngStyle setting?

EDIT: I noticed that if I set width to undefined for the blue panel2, it seems the 2 panels size and align correctly, but I think that is not the correct way.

app.component.html

```
<div #container class="container">
  <div class="section flex-container-row">
    <div [ngStyle]="stylePanel1" class="panel1">1</div>
    <div class="resizer" (click)="startdrag()" (mousedown)="startdrag($event)"></div>
    <div [ngStyle]="stylePanel2" class="panel2 flex-container-row">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="section flex-container-row">
    <div [ngStyle]="stylePanel1" class="panel1">
      <div class="longtext">this is a very long text that should be cut off when resizing.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resizer" (click)="startdrag()" (mousedown)="startdrag($event)"></div>
    <div [ngStyle]="stylePanel2" class="panel2">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.scss

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

.flex-container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.resizer {
  flex: 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.panel2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.longtext {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of  this.refContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth can you please consider 
`refContainer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: @AshishYadav you should add this as an answer. If there's no other better answer I will accept your answer! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.refContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth`.
Can you please consider `refContainer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()`